Reddit Ad Account Id Programmatically using API
I am having issue in getting Reddit ads account id programmatically.
I know how to get the ad account id if it is my account I can just log into account and get it, but I want to get the ad account id of the user whose access token I have.
I am able to access user data using:

https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me

but I am not getting ad account id in it's response.

Endpoints:
To get Profile ID:
https://ads-api.reddit.com/api/v3/me
To get Business ID:
https://ads-api.reddit.com/api/v3/profiles/{profile_id}
To get Ad Account ID:
https://ads-api.reddit.com/api/v3/businesses/{business_id}/ad_accounts
with above steps we can find ad_accounts id.
